# ArcMap ModelBuilder join field error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, iterator

I need to create lines from points using bearing and distance tool. For a mass of files I use Iterator. Also I need to join attribute fields from source point layer to each line layer that made from it. Model works fine except Join field tool. In a Results there is an error message, that result line file does not exist, although previous model step creates it. I guess, that problem can be in workspace parameter of last model operation. I've tried to change parameters of scratch and currennt workspace, but result is the same.

[image: model]

[image: Join Field properties]

Comment: Looks like your question is truncated at the end, please edit.

Comment: Edit your question as @HansErren suggests but also include a screen shot of how your join tool is set up (i.e. what are the parameters?)

Comment: Sorry, can't get the model parameters for a couple of days. @Hornbydd what parameters i need to show?

Comment: Select the Join Field icon and open it to see its properties.

Comment: @danak Properties of Join Field tool are at the post.

Comment: Those are for ModelBuilder, not the actual Join Field screen that describes the type of join and Keep only matching parameters.